# HTTP basic auth for Rack::Static app on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, rack, basic-authentication

I have a simple Rack app hosted on Heroku. config.ru:

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/stylesheets", "/images", "/javascripts"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

How can I add HTTP Basic Auth to this? Bonus points if it only works in the production environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/stylesheets", "/images", "/javascripts"],
  :root => "public"

#SOLUTION:
use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |username, password|
  [username, password] == ['admin', 'admin']
end

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to also protect images, stylesheets and javascripts behind basic auth, you need to put Rack::Auth::Basic first:

```
use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |username, password|
  [username, password] == ['admin', 'admin']
end

use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/stylesheets", "/images", "/javascripts"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```